# how to count the number of palindromes formed by chars in a string?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, encoding

Input Specifications

Your program will take
A string S denoting the set of characters to be tested. All letters in the alphanumeric input will be lowercase (1 ≤ LENGTH(S) ≤ 500)

Output Specifications

Based on the input, print out the total number of unique palindromes that can be created from the input.
Specifically,suppose we have an input string "bbaa", then we have palindromes "baab", "abba", so the total number of palindromes created by input string "bbaa" is 2. The following is the codes I wrote, however, it exceeds the time limit and the algorithm is not efficient. Can someone have some way to construct an algorithms so that we can improve the efficiency?

here is what I wrote for this question:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
public class Problem
{
       private static int count=0;
    public static void main(String[] args)
{

   Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
   //int count=0;
   while(stdin.hasNextLine()) 
   {   String line=stdin.nextLine();
       char[] line_char=line.toCharArray();

       Arrays.sort(line_char);
       StringBuilder strbuild=new StringBuilder("");
       solve(line_char,new boolean[line_char.length],strbuild);
       //System.out.println(stdin.nextLine());
   }
   System.out.println(count);
   stdin.close();
}

    public static void solve(char[] chararray,boolean[] used,StringBuilder strbuild){
    if(strbuild.length()==chararray.length){
        //System.out.println(strbuild.toString());
         if(checkpalindrome(strbuild)){
          count++;
         }
    }else{
        char rec=(char)(chararray[chararray.length-1]+1);
        for(int i=0;i<chararray.length;i++){
          if(!used[i]&&rec!=chararray[i]){
               rec=chararray[i];
               strbuild.append(chararray[i]);
               used[i]=true;
               solve(chararray,used,strbuild);
               strbuild.deleteCharAt(strbuild.length()-1);
               used[i]=false;
          }
        }
    }

}
public static boolean checkpalindrome(StringBuilder strbuild){
     String str=strbuild.toString();
     StringBuilder str1=new StringBuilder(strbuild);
     return str.equals(str1.reverse().toString());
}
```

}

Comment: Suppose we only have one input string! That's why I put System.out.println(count); at the end!

Comment: @GurwinderSingh - Not really a duplicate, because OP is allowed to rearrange the input letters. The question you linked to is to find all substrings that are palindromes.

Comment: Do the palindromes have to use all the input letters? I'm guessing so, since otherwise with your sample input you'd also have palindromes "a", "b", "aa", and "bb" (not to mention the empty string, if that's considered a palindrome). But it's worth asking.

Comment: yes,we need to use all the chars of input string

Comment: This should be on Codereview.

Comment: @0x499602D2 - I disagree. The question isn't about the code, but about a better algorithm. That's on-topic for SO.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much simpler way of counting palindromes. I'm not going to write code for you, but I'll describe the approach.

Since you have to use all characters of the input, then you can have at most one character that occurs an odd number of times. So you should check for that condition first. If there's more than one letter with an odd count, then the answer has to be zero. Otherwise, take the odd letter (if any) and imagine it in the middle of the output string. Then all remaining letters occur an even number of times. But now generating palindromes is equivalent of taking half the number of each letter count and generating all unique permutations of those letters. There would then be a palindrome for each permutation, formed by the permutation, the letter in the middle (if applicable), and the reverse of the permutation.

So all you have to do is count all unique permutations of half the letters (after dealing with the single odd letter if present). That should be easier to do more efficiently than your current approach.